# Android: Custom Oscilliscope View Scan Rate

Tags: android, android-view

I have written a custom view that shows a simulated oscilloscope, it essentially holds a series of points to plot, and periodically places a pulse (a separate set of points) into the main series. The only problem is that I'd like to update the points at the correct rate of 25mm/sec on one plot and 4mm/sec on another.

`setRate()` is called before the view is drawn. `updateData()` is called from a thread that runs a loop at 60fps with `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`. The problem is that  `pxToDraw` is not the right value to keep it at the rate I'd like.

Here is my code

```
static class FakePlot extends OscView.Plot {

  public void setRate(int width, DisplayMetrics dm) {
    float xdpi = dm.xdpi;
    mWidthMm = width/ xdpi * 25.4f;
    pxPerSec =TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, mScanRateMM, dm);
    pxPerTick = ((float)width) / mData.length;
    lastPulse = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    Log.e(TAG,String.format("setRate() %s: pxPerSec=%f pxPerTick=%f",mTitle,pxPerSec,pxPerTick));
  }

    /**
     * Copy the next set of points along
     * @param realTime
     */
    public void updateData(long realTime) {
        long diff = realTime - lastUpdate;
        lastUpdate = realTime;
        float pxToDraw = ((diff/1000f)/pxPerSec);
        float ticksToDraw = pxToDraw/(1f/pxPerTick);
        for (int j = 0; j < ticksToDraw; j++){
            // update mData with the next ticksToDrawPoints
        }
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

A full working example (without the correct scan rate is here: http://pastebin.com/nHBxumhV)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
float extraToDraw;
public void updateData(long realTime) {
    float mmPerTick = mWidthMm/mData.length;
    float mmToDraw = (mScanRateMM*diffSec)+extraToDraw; 
    if(mmToDraw < 1) {extraToDraw = mmToDraw;return;}
    extraToDraw = 0;
    float drawn = 0;
    while(drawn < mmToDraw) {
        drawn+= mmPerTick;
        // draw the next tick
    }
}
```